# Getting error while converting varchar into int of selected row of gridview in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms

```
I am deleting selected row from grid view.
```

with following code row is deleted from gridview but not from the database. it shows me error of converting varchar to int

```
Private Sub dltButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dltButton.Click
            'Dim StudentId As String
            'StudentId =
            'con.Open()
            'cmd.CommandText = "delete from KaiyumVbStudent where StudentID = '"&StudentId&"'"
            'cmd.Connection = con
            Dim i As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
            DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.CurrentRow)
            StudentID = CType(DataGridView1.SelectedCells(2), TextBox).Text
            con = New SqlConnection(constring)
            con.Open()
            cmd = New SqlCommand("Delete from KaiyumVbStudent where StudentID = '@StudentID'", con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Call databind()
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is because you have quotes enclosing your parameter.

That is, this:

```
Delete from KaiyumVbStudent where StudentID = '@StudentID'
```

Should probably read as this (note no quotes around **@StudentID**):

```
Delete from KaiyumVbStudent where StudentID = @StudentID
```

However, I don't see where you are adding/setting the parameter in your code for `@StudentID`.

Answer (score 0):

You might not get a datatype conversion error when executing where `StudentID='1'` however, agree with comment above in the it looks like you are not setting the parameter value. So effectively it is executing the following SQL:

`Delete from KaiyumVbStudent where StudentID = '@StudentID'`